# Find a ip next line inside a while

Tags: tcl

Inside a "while" I need to verify if in a next line on lindex position 1 I have the same ip on this round.

If yes, do something, if not do another thing.

ips.txt

```
169.254.0.1,169.254.1.1
169.254.0.2,169.254.1.1
169.254.0.3,169.254.1.2
169.254.0.4,169.254.1.2
```

How can I do this with tcl?

Thanks.

Comment: Some clarification is needed. Does "position 1" refer to the ip address after the comma? It seems like you would want to check the ip address after the comma against the ip address after the comma on the previous line, is that correct? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @PeterLewerin, its correct. I need to verify if a second ip on next line is the same on previous line. I try increment a line or some other stuff, but none of this work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly simplistic, but should do the job:

```
set ch [open ips.txt]
set prev {}
while {[chan gets $ch ips] >= 0} {
    lassign [split $ips ,] ipa ipb
    if {$prev ne {}} {
        if {$prev eq $ipb} {
            # do something
        } else {
            # do another thing
        }
    } else {
        # do something with the first line
    }
    set prev $ipb
}
chan close $ch
```

From the inside out: based on the values in `prev` (the second ip address from the previous line, or the empty string if we're reading the first line) and `ipb` (the second ip address from the current line) being equal or not, do "something" or "another thing". Both ip addresses in the line are available for processing as the values of `ipa` and `ipb`.

To make sure we're only doing this when we have valid addresses to compare (note that this gives you the option to preset `prev` to a default value), this comparison is wrapped inside a comparison between `$prev` and the empty string.

On each line, before anything is compared, split the line into two addresses and store them in `ipa` and `ipb`. After the comparison, copy the value from `ibp` to `prev` to be used when processing the next line.

Read and process all the lines from the file.

This script will raise an error exception if unable to open the file for reading. Malformed lines in the file shouldn't cause problems but might set `ipb` to the empty string.

Documentation: [chan](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/chan.htm), [if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm), [lassign](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lassign.htm), [open](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/open.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm), [while](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/while.htm)